# Calculate percentage .asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am looking to build a webpage that submits into a database (.asp) but also calculates a percentage.

The percentage amount is 8%.

Ideally I want the user to type an amount in an input box (for example lets say £100)

Then underneath there is another input box which automatically caluates the £100 + 8% (so £108)

I haven't got a clue how to start so I haven't got any code

Comment: you can start using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mB3Q/

This is your jQuery:

```
$("#val").on('keyup', function(){
    $("#incPerc").text(parseInt($(this).val())*1.08);
});
```

you might want to use a library to limit the input to digits only. 
something like this: [Limit Textfield Input to digits only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075699/limit-textfield-input-to-digits-only)

added the second input http://jsfiddle.net/5mB3Q/1/
and the round of two digits:

```
$("#val").on('keyup', function(){
    var withPerc = parseFloat($(this).val())*1.08;
    $("#incPerc").text(withPerc.toFixed(2));
    $("#otherInput").val(withPerc.toFixed(2));
});
```

**edit**: ok, full code because of the comment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="val">
      <input id="otherInput">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#val").on('keyup', function(){ 
                var withPerc = parseFloat($(this).val())*0.08; 
                $("#incPerc").text(withPerc.toFixed(2)); 
                $("#otherInput").val(withPerc.toFixed(2)); 
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You forgot the protocol when you linked the jQuery lib. (and doc.ready)

Comment: Thanks JP, I need the calucation in another input box if possible? I need to submit both numbers into the database

Comment: Sure, no problem. `$("#idOtherTextBox").val(parseInt($(this).val())*1.08);`

Comment: Just thought, how can I make it work with decimals. For example 10.50?

Comment: As you can see, I have changed the int to float ;) `parseFloat`

Comment: Thanks again JP Hellemons. That is perfect

Comment: I can't get the code to work on my webpage. I am probably doing something really simple. <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> <title>Untitled Document</title> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $("#val").on('keyup', function(){ var withPerc = parseFloat($(this).val())*0.08; $("#incPerc").text(withPerc.toFixed(2)); $("#otherInput").val(withPerc.toFixed(2)); }); </script> </head> <body> <input id="val"> <input id="otherInput"/> </body> </html>

Comment: Hi JP, is there something that will cause this to stop working on IE8?

Comment: Ok fixed it, had to link to 1.9 jquery as 2.0 doesn't work with IE

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#output').text = (int)($('#input').text.Substring(0, $('#input').text.Length - 1)) * 1,08 + $('#input').text.Substring($('#input').text.Length - 1);
```